# get every Sunday between a date frame in sql 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need get every Sunday between date range. For example if my startdate is 07/27/2014 and End date is '08/10/2014', then i need a table have 
07/27/2014,
08/03/2014,
08/10/2014

```
    select '2014/7/27' 
    union all
    select dateadd(day, 7,'2014/7/27')
   where '2014/7/27' <= '2014/8/10'
```

only give me 07/27/2014 and 08/03/2014. please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're trying to do this as a recursive query the format is

```
WITH cteSundays as ( 
    select dateadd(day, 0, '2014/7/27') as Sunday  
    union all  
    select dateadd(day, 7,Sunday)   
    FROM cteSundays  
    where Sunday <= dateadd(day, -7, '2014/8/10')  
) SELECT * FROM cteSundays
```

but keep in mind that these are limited by the recursive depth allowed. I think 2012 is about 100 but you should experiment to make sure it can handle your needs.

EDIT: Oops, the original went an extra week, you need to subtract 7 days from the end condition

Answer (score 1):

Something like below will work

```
declare @startdate datetime, @enddate datetime
set @startdate='20140727'
set @enddate='20140810'
select dateadd(week,number,@startdate) from master..spt_values where type='p' and 
dateadd(week,number,@startdate) <=@enddate
```

Answer (score 0):

One method, assuming the @StartDate is a Sunday:

```
DECLARE 
      @StartDate date = '2014-07-27'
    , @EndDate date = '2014-08-10';
WITH 
      t4 AS (SELECT n FROM (VALUES(0),(0),(0),(0)) t(n))
    , t256 AS (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) - 1 AS n FROM t4 AS a CROSS JOIN t4 AS b CROSS JOIN t4 AS c CROSS JOIN t4 AS d)
SELECT DATEADD(day, n * 7, @StartDate)
FROM t256
WHERE DATEADD(day, n * 7, @StartDate) < = @EndDate;
```